# Naming convention "by" vs "with" vs "using"

Tags: naming-conventions

I have a project where we have a mix of different naming when a function needs to find an object using a property given in parameter. I am wondering if there is a naming convention for the following:

```
function getObjectUsingName(name){} // A
function getObjectByName(name){}    // B
function getObjectWithName(name){}  // C
```

More basically, it there a different meaning between them or it is only a matter of choosing one?

Comment: Consider `getObjectNamed(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is only matters for easy to read the code. And usually people choose "by". So function getObjectByName(name){} would be the nicest way but it is only based on my experience.